# Ada pragma Pack or Alignment attribute for Records?

Tags: ada, memory-alignment

Having just discovered alignment issues for the first time I am unsure on which method is the best/safest way to deal with them.  I have a record which I am serialising to send over a Stream and vice-versa so it must meet the interface spec and contain no padding.

Given the example record:

```
type MyRecord is record
a : Unsigned_8;
b : Unsigned_32;
end record;
```

This by default would require 8 bytes but I am able to remove packing using 2 methods:

```
for MyRecord'Alignment use 1;
```

or

```
pragma Pack (MyRecord);
```

I have found a few questions relating to C examples but haven't been able to find a clear answer on which method is the most appropriate, how to determine which method to use or if they are equivalent?

**UPDATE**

When I tried both on my 'real' code rather than a basic example I found that the Alignment attribute achieved what I was looking for.  pragma Pack significantly reduced the size, not confirmed but I assume it has packed the many enumerated types I'm using, overriding the 'Size use 8 attribute applied to each type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [Streams](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-13-1.html) you could leave `MyRecord` without any representation clauses and use the default `MyRecord’Write` and `MyRecord’Read`; [ARM 13.13.2(9)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-13-13-2.html) says

> For elementary types, Read reads (and Write writes) the number of stream elements implied by the Stream_Size for the type T; the representation of those stream elements is implementation defined. For composite types, the Write or Read attribute for each component is called in canonical order, which is last dimension varying fastest for an array (unless the convention of the array is Fortran, in which case it is first dimension varying fastest), and positional aggregate order for a record.

One possible disadvantage of the GNAT implementation (and maybe of others) is that the `’Write` and `’Read` calls each end in a call to the underlying network software. Not a problem (aside from possible inefficiency) normally, but if you’re using `TCP_NODELAY` (or worse, UDP) this is *not* the behaviour you’re looking for.

Overloading `’Write` leads back to your original problem (but at least it’s confined to the overloading procedure, so the rest of your program can deal with properly aligned data).

I’ve used an in-memory stream for this (especially the UDP case); `’Write` to the in-memory stream, then send the `Stream_Element_Array` to the socket. One example is `ColdFrame.Memory_Streams` ([.ads](https://sourceforge.net/p/coldframe/code/ci/default/tree/lib/coldframe-memory_streams.ads), [.adb](https://sourceforge.net/p/coldframe/code/ci/default/tree/lib/coldframe-memory_streams.adb)).

Comment: +1. Packing should be used to control the in-memory representation, not the stream representation. If you need a specific format "on the wire" (because the other end expects that format) you can overload the default procedures to produce that format, regardless of the packing in memory.

Comment: When I do this it sends one field per packet rather than the whole serialised record per packet?

Comment: Thanks Simon. The edit looks like the solution to my problem. I am currently using a Stream Element Array as it makes it easy to meet a couple of my application requirements. I found the alignment issues whilst attempting unchecked conversion to stream element array. This should also solve my final problem where the unchecked conversion put unsigned_32 LSB (byte) first where my stream spec is MSB first

Comment: If your stream spec is entirely big-endian (aka network byte order), you might want to look at modifying your Ada runtime to automatically convert to/from network byte order, as hinted at [on c.l.a, some time ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ada/GbC_W2kG0uc/oez_mEoyZs4J). I see that with GNAT GPL 2015 the XDR version of `System.Stream_Attributes` is in `s-stratt-xdr.adb`; likewise FSF GCC 5 (but that doesn’t have the `Makefile.adalib` you need, you could probably copy it).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the record representation clauses, if you want full control:

```
for MyRecord'Size use 40;
for MyRecord use record 
    a at 0 range 0 .. 7;
    b at 1 range 0 .. 31;
end record;
```

(or some such, I might have messed up some of the indices here).

NB: edited as per comment by Simon

Comment: `b at 1 range 0 .. 31` I think!

Comment: Is the representation clause relevant for writing to a stream?  (Too lazy to look it up right now.)

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen : for a stream, I'd define my own Read and Write to define the wire format, independently of how the compiler packs the record in memory.